# Doubt regarding derivation of relativistic Bernoulli function

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

The relativistic form of the radial momentum equation for spherical fluid flow is
$$\gamma_v^2v\frac{dv}{dr}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dp}{dr}+\frac{d\Phi}{dr}=0$$
where $\gamma_v=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ is the Lorentz factor and $\Phi$ is the gravitational potential.

The specific enthalpy of the flow is expressed as $h=u+\dfrac{P}{\rho}$, where $u$ is the specific energy. Using the first law of thermodynamics, we obtain $dh=Tds+\dfrac{dp}{\rho}$, so that $ds=\dfrac{dp}{\rho}$ for an isentropic flow. Thus, the above equation reduces to
$$\boxed{\gamma_v^2v\frac{dv}{dr}+\frac{dh}{dr}+\frac{d\Phi}{dr}=0}$$

**CASE 1:**

In the non-relativistic limit, $v\ll1$, and this means $\gamma_v=1$, and the radial momentum equation reduces to
$$v\frac{dv}{dr}+\frac{dh}{dr}+\frac{d\Phi}{dr}=0$$
Integrating this equation one obtains the Bernoulli function
$$\mathscr{B}=\frac{v^2}{2}+h+\Phi\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(1)$$

**CASE 2:**

To obtain the Bernoulli function for relativistic flow, we need to retain the Lorentz factor, so that the radial momentum equation is
$$\frac{v}{1-v^2}\frac{dv}{dr}+\frac{dh}{dr}+\frac{d\Phi}{dr}=0$$
Thus, the Bernoulli function can be obtained as
$$\mathscr{B}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)+h+\Phi\qquad\qquad\qquad(2)$$

**Question:**

> The non-relativistic Bernoulli function (eqn.$1$) is a well-known
> expression found in most textbooks, but I am not sure whether the
> relativistic Bernoulli function (eqn.$2$) that I had derived is
> correct or not. Am I doing the correct calculations? If not, can
> someone suggest the correct approach?

Comment: Of possible related interest:   https://puhep1.princeton.edu//~kirkmcd/examples/bernoulli.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I thnk you can compare your work with [this page](https://www.mendozza.org/sergio/phdthesis/phdlatex2html/node18.html).  It's chock-full of rendered equations, ending with this conclusion:

> where $v$ is the flow velocity and the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ is given by
>
> $$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
>
> The time component of eq. $(9.6)$ is implied by the other three. In the case of isentropic flow, that is, when $\sigma/n=const.$, and assuming the flow to be steady, the spatial components of eq. $(9.6)$ give
>
> $$\gamma(v\cdot grad)(\gamma\omega v/n)+c^2grad(\omega/n)=0$$
>
> Scalar multiplication by $v$ leads to
>
> $$(v\cdot grad)(\gamma\omega/n)=0$$
>
> which implies that along any streamline the quantity
>
> $$\gamma\omega/n=const.$$
>
> This is the relativistic version of Bernoulli's equation.

Another, somewhat longer and deeper analysis can be found [here](https://luth.obspm.fr/%7Eluthier/gourgoulhon/pdf/Gourg06.pdf).

Comment: Props to @Jonas  for re-coding the equations from the original jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for the lorentz factor is wrong:
$$\gamma_v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\neq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}.$$
The non relativistic case is $v\ll c$ and **not** $v \ll 1$. This makes your second approach equivalent to your first, which leads to the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention in the question that I have chosen geometrized units $G=M=c=1$.